# Loop to start at a cell and delete the next 600 in the column

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop

All of my data is in the "D" column.

I want to start a specific cell (ie. D249) and then select the next 600 and delete them (ie. D250-D850). Then I want to skip the next one down (ie. D851) and delete the next 600 below that. I want to do this until it gets to the end, which is like D19000.  I think I need to use a while loop to check if data is present in the cell I'm looking at.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub delete600rows()
'delete600rows Macro
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a

ActiveSheet.Range("D249").Select
While LEN()>0

Range("D249:D848").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

How do I write the condition for the while loop and how do I make the range select work the way I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one below should work. I have not tested it extensively. I put an option where you can select the cell you want to start from and how many rows you want to delete. If those are standard just hard code them in the code :)

```
Sub deleteNumOfrows()
Dim myBook As Workbook
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim startCell As Range
Dim numOfRowsToDelete As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Set your workbook - in this version I select the active workbook
Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook

'Set up your worksheet - In this version I select the active worksheet
Set mySheet = myBook.ActiveSheet

'Select the cell you want to start
Set startCell = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a cell", Type:=8)

'Input how many rows you want to delete - If it is always 600 just set it to that
numOfRowsToDelete = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Number of rows to delete each time")

'Find the last row data exists in the column of the startCell
lastRow = mySheet.Cells(mySheet.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Delete the rows you do not want
i = startCell.Row 'Start from the row of the startCell

While i <= lastRow 'Repeat while you haven't reached the last row
    'mySheet.Rows((i + 1) & ":" & (i + numOfRowsToDelete)).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete the rows
    mySheet.Range(Cells((i + 1), startCell.Column), Cells((i + numOfRowsToDelete), startCell.Column)).Delete Shift:=xlUp  'Delete the range you dont want
    i = i + 1 'Next row
    lastRow = lastRow - numOfRowsToDelete 'Adjust lastRow
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! This actually worked well! The only issue is that I think we need to do a different style of deleting, because the D row ends before rows A,B,C, and E.

Comment: I realised I misunderstood your request. I just modified the code so it deletes only the cells in the column you want :)

Comment: I'm still having issues with it ending column D prematurely, while the other ones just go on. With the new code though, the other columns continue on to 19,000+. In the original code you posted, the other columns ended at around 1000.

Comment: When you say "it ending column D prematurely" you mean excel freezes up ?

Comment: No, excel doesn't freeze up. The data set has 5 columns from A to E, and they all run to the same length. In other words, the last value is in A19000,B19000,C19000,D19000,E19000. It isn't actually 19000; that is just the round number I chose. The problematic data that needs to be deleted is in column D. The way it should work is that when all the data in column D is deleted, all the columns have the same length. In your second code, the data in column D ends at D500, while the other columns end at A19000.

Comment: I see. Then the first version of the code should work as it deletes the entire row. Alternatively you could replace 'startCell.Column' in the delete line with the columns you want to delete (e.g. 1 for A at the first occurence and 5 for E at the second occurence), as that would be faster than deleting an entire row

Comment: I went back to the original code and tried it again and it worked! I may have executed it improperly the first time. Thank you so much man!! I really appreciate the help! Definitely going to teach myself VBA outside of work now!

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, commenting not yet possible for me.)

I'm a little confused I have to say: Why would you only want to delete 600 rows if you can just delete everything from cell D249 downwards? Is there something you are looking for in this column? What is the use of this?

Otherwise there would be a possibility to check for the last row:

```
Dim LastRow as Long
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
```

And then you could just delete everything from D249 to the last filled row in your workbook.

If I am wrong, there would really be some more clarification neccessairy.

Comment: Essentially, we have a lot of extraneous data in the "D" column. For example, in between 21.1 and 21.2, we have 600 data points. We want to count by .10, so we want to keep 21.1 and 21.2 and 21.3, but we want to get rid of those 600 data points between those values.

Comment: I've realized it would be easier to use a "Do Until" loop. Here is the new code, but I'm still not sure how to select the range of just deleting the next 600 cells.

    Range("D249").Select
    
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Range("D249:D848").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop
    
    End Sub

Comment: So you want to delete 250-850 then leave 851 in the workbook then delete 852-1452 leave 1453 in the workbook and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Until the end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You count use a for loop and add instance of 501, the cyntax is off, but I grew up in php

```
start = 249
len = 500 

for (i=0;i=100;i++) {
    from = (i*(len+1)+start
    to = from+len
    range.select("D" & from & ":D" & to
    if (range.select("D" & from).value = ""){
       break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Sub test()

 Dim LR As Long
 Dim Rng As Range

 LR = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Debug.Print LR
 If LR < 851 Then
  Set Rng = Range("D250:D850")
 Else
   For i = 249 To LR Step 601
    j = j + 1
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
     Set Rng = Range(Cells(i + j, "D"), Cells(i + j + 600, "D"))
    Else
     Set Rng = Union(Rng, Range(Cells(i + j, "D"), Cells(i + j + 600, "D")))
    End If
   Next
 End If

 Rng.Delete xlUp
End Sub
```

If you want to delete Entire Row replace `Rng.Delete xlUp` with `Rng.EntireRow.Delete`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an idea for you to adapt than the correct code:

```
Dim StartRow As Integer
StartRow = 249
Dim DelRow As Integer
DelRow = 600
Dim LastRow AS Integer
LastRow = ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

If Not (LastRow + 1) Then

'I don't know if this will work, if you can test for the end of the table
'differently, I believe this would be better (maybe even "Do Until (LastRow + 1)")

    ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet.Range("D" & (StartRow + 1):"D" & (StartRow + 1 + DelRow).Delete
    StartRow = StartRow + 1
End If
```

Something like this could work as you always delete 600 Rows at a time  then you want to keep the next. So after you have deleted the range 250-850 the row 250 is now containing what was in row 851 before deleting it.