# Start counter loop in specific cell and end in specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a loop counter that starts in Range(A9) and Ends in Range(A38) max. The cells above "A9" and below "A38" have text and are locked cells. I found some code on this site and tried to modify it to fit my needs but I'm getting a ("Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"). Not sure what that means exactly. Here's my code below.

```
Private Sub cmdsGO_Click()
Dim myWrkBk As Workbook
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim startCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Range
Dim i As Long

Set myWrkBk = ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myWrkBk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set startCell = Range("'Sheet1'! A9")

lastRow = Range("'Sheet1'!A38") 

While i <= lastRow
   i = i + 1
Wend    
End Sub
```

I'm using a command button to start the loop. Range("A9") to Range("A38") is 30 numbers. So, of course, the counter should start on 1 and end at 30 but its not. Thank you.

The original location that I found this code is:
[Loop to start at a cell and delete the next 600 in the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679569/loop-to-start-at-a-cell-and-delete-the-next-600-in-the-column)

Answer (score 0):

Try a Data Series.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdsGO_Click()
    Dim myWrkBk As Workbook
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet

    Set myWrkBk = ActiveWorkbook
    Set mySheet = myWrkBk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With mySheet
        .Cells(9, "A") = 1
        .Range(.Cells(9, "A"), .Cells(38, "A")).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
    End With
End Sub
```

Your own code wasn't working due to a range object (e.g. lastRow) first being assigned a value from Range("'Sheet1'!A38") instead of being Set to the range object then used as an integer in the For Next loop.

Comment: Would mind explaining what the code does in between the "With and End With". I understand the first part, I think, your assigning 1 to cell 9A. Right? The reason why I am asking, eventually I'm probably going to build off this formula. Example: if there a number value in column A lets say cell (A9) then there may be values in cells (E9),(F9), and (G9). Thank you very much for your help.